# How to exclude a certain linenumber of an Ansible playbook when testing it using Molecule?

Tags: ansible, yaml, molecule, linting

The aim is to exclude a certain line that contains a checksum and cannot be smaller than 80 characters.

```
--> Scenario: 'default'
--> Action: 'lint'
--> Executing Yamllint on files found in /tmp/ansible-firefox/...
    /tmp/ansible-firefox/defaults/main.yml
      2:81      error    line too long (153 > 80 characters)  (line-length)
```

defaults/main.yml

```
firefox_checksum: sha512:49d776cfb5f42c6e5ea1a55a80d9f6bad223080b16baa0d39de63534c25e68340091b4e16be5355d565f81291cb94fb996f03ae7e3e4c7a28021b0a0929daf58
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the yamllint documentation](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/disable_with_comments.html#disabling-checks-for-a-specific-line) you need to add a special comment to the line -- `<string-to-be-excluded>  # yamllint disable-line rule:line-length`

```
---
#defaults/main
firefox_checksum: sha512:49d776cfb5f42c6e5ea1a55a80d9f6bad223080b16baa0d39de63534c25e68340091b4e16be5355d565f81291cb94fb996f03ae7e3e4c7a28021b0a0929daf58 #yamllint disable-line rule:line-length
```

Comment: Note that there should be two spaces after the the string to be excluded and that a space should reside in front of the yamllint in order to exclude yaml lint length testing for a certain line number (see [this](https://github.com/030/ansible-firefox/blob/a6ce5325a790293b895606c203afe254ab2b4d6f/defaults/main.yml#L2))